# Improve randomization function (from 1 to 2)

Tags: optimization, delphi

I am trying to do a randomize function.  It randomly selects one person (from two) to insert something into the console.  The second person goes next, and then they keep alternating until the loop ends.

```
  randomize();
  RandomTurn := random(2)+1;  
  while (1) do
  begin
      if RandomTurn = 1 then 
        PersonTurn((NumberOfMoves mod 2)+1)
      else 
        PersonTurn(round(2/((NumberOfMoves mod 2)+1)));

      NumberOfMoves := NumberOfMoves + 1;
  end;
```

What do you think? How could this function be improved based on number of moves/user inputs?

Comment: What's the argument to `PersonTurn()` and why do you need it?

Comment: There are two persons who are changing in their turn like in chess or any other game, so I wanted to do a fnction which will always turn another person BUT at the begining it chooses randomly on of them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Randomness

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946869/how-reliable-is-the-random-function-in-delphi) suggests that `Random(2)` would be okay for most uses. If you want more randomness, you could for example use an implementation of [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister). [This page](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/PASCAL/pascal.html) lists a few options for Pascal/Delphi, for example [this implementation](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/PASCAL/nicholls.txt).

#### Alternating values

Now that I know what you are looking for, I would write the code like this:

```
// If Value is divisible by 2 then return 1, otherwise return 2
procedure AlternateValue(Value) : ShortInt;
begin
    if Value mod 2 = 0 then Result := 1 else Result := 2
end;

// Your code
randomize();
RandomTurn := random(2)+1;
NumberOfMoves := RandomTurn

while (1) do
begin
    PersonTurn(AlternateValue(NumberOfMoves))
    NumberOfMoves := NumberOfMoves + 1;
end;
```

You should swap the two lines in the `while` loop if you want to start with the same number as `Random` gives. From what I gather, it should not matter much, however.

(I have never written any Pascal or Delphi before, so the code and/or syntax may not be perfect or correct.)

Comment: Yes I need to randomize first input to be randomly 1 or 2 and after that changing 1 - 2 - 1 - 2 etc. So only first number will be random and then others will always change, does this code of yours do that?

Comment: @Byakugan: To switch between `1` and `2`, you could just do `NewValue := 3 - OldValue`: `3 - 1` -> `2`, `3 - 2` -> `1`.

Comment: Yes, the code I posted would do that. I have revised my answer, however, to indicate how I would write it now that I understand what you are after. You could also do as @AndriyM suggests, but I think my example is cleaner and more readable, because it states exactly what the intent of the code is. Does this answer your question?

Comment: My snippet had a bug, because I forgot to do `mod 2`. That is fixed now.

Comment: @AndriyM Or `Result := Value mod 2 + 1;`. It would be cleaner to use `0` and `1` rather than `1` and `2`...

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: Indeed, and I like your suggestion better than mine. As for whether it would be cleaner to use 0 & 1 instead of 1 & 2 in this particular case, I'm not sure. To switch between the former, you would do `Result := (Value + 1) mod 2;` – not much difference from the formula you've suggested for 1 & 2. (Although I'd agree that in most cases 0-based indices are easiest to work with.)

Comment: @AndriyM The whole point of my suggestion is that `i mod 2` alternates between `0` and `1` for increasing `i`. So `Result := Value mod 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

I would improve the readability a bit by using:

```
PersonToPlay := RandomInitial();
For i:=MoveIndex := 1 to TotalNumberOfMoves do begin
  PersonTurn(PersonToPlay);
  PersonToPlay := 3 - PersonToPlay;
end;
```

To make it even more readable:

```
PersonToPlay := RandomInitial();
For i:=MoveIndex := 1 to TotalNumberOfMoves do begin
  PersonTurn(PersonToPlay);
  PersonToPlay := TheOtherPlayer(PersonToPlay);
end;
....

Function TheOtherPlayer (aPlayer : TPlayer) : TPlayer;
Begin
  if aPlayer := ThisPlayer then 
    Result := ThatPlayer
  else
    Result := ThisPlayer;
End;
```

Rate Readability over Speed (usually). Make your code comment itself.